# How can I get timestamps on previously connected USB devices?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, usb-drive, computer-forensics

I'm trying to get an old PowerShell script to show the times of previously connected USB devices. After having read a few forensics [blogs](http://nicoleibrahim.com/tag/usb-devices/) like [this](http://techgenix.com/extracting-usb-artifacts-from-windows-7/), I found [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-USBHistory-707e43a3/)  from [this blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/18/use-powershell-to-find-the-history-of-usb-flash-drive-usage/). (Script by Jason Walker.)

Unfortunately it doesn't show any **timestamps** or any other useful details about the devices. So I was hoping [there should be a way to get that too](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/454084/getting-usb-storage-usage-history). Only I fail to see how to incorporate this.

```powershell
Function Get-USBHistory { 
 [CmdletBinding()] 
Param 
( 
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True)] 
    [alias("CN","Computer")] 
    [String[]]$ComputerName=$Env:COMPUTERNAME, 
    [Switch]$Ping     
) 

 Begin { 
     $TempErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference 
     $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" 
     $Hive   = "LocalMachine" 
     $Key    = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR" 
  } 

  Process 
  {             
     $USBDevices      = @() 
     $ComputerCounter = 0         

     ForEach($Computer in $ComputerName) 
     { 
        $USBSTORSubKeys1 = @() 
        $ChildSubkeys    = @() 
        $ChildSubkeys1   = @() 

        $ComputerCounter++         
        $Computer = $Computer.Trim().ToUpper() 
        Write-Progress -Activity "Collecting USB history" -Status "Retrieving USB history from $Computer" -PercentComplete (($ComputerCounter/($ComputerName.Count)*100)) 


        If($Ping) 
        { 
           If(-not (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) 
           { 
              Write-Warning "Ping failed on $Computer" 
              Continue 
           } 
        }#end if ping  

         Try 
         { 
            $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($Hive,$Computer) 
            $USBSTORKey = $Reg.OpenSubKey($Key) 
            $USBSTORSubKeys1  = $USBSTORKey.GetSubKeyNames() 
         }#end try              
         Catch 
         { 
            Write-Warning "There was an error connecting to the registry on $Computer or USBSTOR key not found. Ensure the remote registry service is running on the remote machine." 
         }#end catch 

         ForEach($SubKey1 in $USBSTORSubKeys1) 
         {     
            $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue" 
            $Key2 = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\$SubKey1" 
            $RegSubKey2  = $Reg.OpenSubKey($Key2) 
            $SubkeyName2 = $RegSubKey2.GetSubKeyNames() 

            $ChildSubkeys   += "$Key2\$SubKeyName2" 
            $RegSubKey2.Close()         
         }#end foreach SubKey1 

         ForEach($Child in $ChildSubkeys) 
         { 

            If($Child -match " ") 
            { 
               $BabySubkey = $null 
               $ChildSubkey1 = ($Child.split(" "))[0] 

               $SplitChildSubkey1 = $ChildSubkey1.split("\") 

               0..4 | Foreach{ [String]$BabySubkey += ($SplitChildSubkey1[$_]) + "\"}  

               $ChildSubkeys1 += $BabySubkey + ($Child.split(" ")[-1]) 
               $ChildSubkeys1 += $ChildSubkey1 

            } 
            Else 
            { 
               $ChildSubkeys1 += $Child 
            } 
                $ChildSubKeys1.count 
         }#end foreach ChildSubkeys 

         ForEach($ChildSubkey1 in $ChildSubkeys1) 
         {     
            $USBKey      = $Reg.OpenSubKey($ChildSubkey1) 
            $USBDevice   = $USBKey.GetValue('FriendlyName')  
            If($USBDevice) 
            {     
               $USBDevices += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{ 
                     USBDevice = $USBDevice 
                     Computer  = $Computer 
                     Serial    = $ChildSubkey1.Split("\")[-1] 
                       } 
             } 
                 $USBKey.Close()                                           
          }#end foreach ChildSubKey2 

                 $USBSTORKey.Close()            
         #Display results         
     $USBDevices | Select Computer,USBDevice,Serial 
     }#end foreach computer  

  }#end process 

  End 
  {         
     #Set error action preference back to original setting         
     $ErrorActionPreference = $TempErrorAction          
  } 

}#end function
```

And the C# code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string usbStor = @"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR";
        using (var keyUsbStor = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(usbStor))
        {
            var usbDevices = from className in keyUsbStor.GetSubKeyNames()
                             let keyUsbClass = keyUsbStor.OpenSubKey(className)
                             from instanceName in keyUsbClass.GetSubKeyNames()
                             let keyUsbInstance = new RegistryKeyEx(keyUsbClass.OpenSubKey(instanceName))
                             select new
                             {
                                 UsbName = keyUsbInstance.Key.GetValue("FriendlyName"),
                                 ConnectTime = keyUsbInstance.LastWriteTime
                             };
            foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices.OrderBy(x => x.ConnectTime))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("({0}) -- '{1}'", usbDevice.ConnectTime, usbDevice.UsbName);
            }
        }
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Wraps a RegistryKey object and corresponding last write time.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// .NET doesn't expose the last write time for a registry key 
/// in the RegistryKey class, so P/Invoke is required.
/// </remarks>
public class RegistryKeyEx
{
    #region P/Invoke Declarations
    // This declaration is intended to be used for the last write time only. int is used
    // instead of more convenient types so that dummy values of 0 reduce verbosity.
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
    extern private static int RegQueryInfoKey(
        SafeRegistryHandle hkey,
        int lpClass,
        int lpcbClass,
        int lpReserved,
        int lpcSubKeys,
        int lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
        int lpcbMaxClassLen,
        int lpcValues,
        int lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
        int lpcbMaxValueLen,
        int lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
        IntPtr lpftLastWriteTime);
    #endregion
    #region Public Poperties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the registry key owned by the info object.
    /// </summary>
    public RegistryKey Key { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the last write time for the corresponding registry key.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; private set; }
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new RegistryKeyInfo object from the provided RegistryKey object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">RegistryKey component providing a handle to the key.</param>
    public RegistryKeyEx(RegistryKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
        SetLastWriteTime();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new RegistryKeyInfo object from a registry key path string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Parent key for the key being loaded.</param>
    /// <param name="keyName">Path to the registry key.</param>
    public RegistryKeyEx(RegistryKey parent, string keyName)
        : this(parent.OpenSubKey(keyName))
    { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Queries the currently set registry key through P/Invoke for the last write time.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetLastWriteTime()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Key != null, "RegistryKey component must be initialized");
        GCHandle pin = new GCHandle();
        long lastWriteTime = 0;
        try
        {
            pin = GCHandle.Alloc(lastWriteTime, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            if (RegQueryInfoKey(Key.Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, pin.AddrOfPinnedObject()) == 0)
            {
                LastWriteTime = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)pin.Target);
            }
            else
            {
                LastWriteTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pin.IsAllocated)
            {
                pin.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Sorry, I can't get the PSH code to highlight correctly.)

**How can I use this to improve the script?**

---

Update: 2017-11-06

Following @iRon's suggestion, I tried to directly access the registry path: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\<drive>\Propertie‌​s`, using RegEdit, but then I got a permission error, which is strange, as my user account is Admin. (This is on Win8.1)

[image]

A few other options I found are:

1. To use Windows built-in [Event Viewer](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-track-down-usb-flash-drive-usage-in-windows-10s-event-viewer/) and make a Custom view. However, this require you to have alreay enabled the event logs.
2. Similarly use the [logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659) with a CMD batch [script](https://df-stream.com/download/327/) as shown [here](https://df-stream.com/2014/01/the-windows-7-event-log-and-usb-device/) and [here](https://df-stream.com/2014/02/usb-device-tracking-batch-scrip/). (Require enabled event logs.)
3. Follow the forensics as described [here](https://www.blackbagtech.com/blog/2017/02/14/analyzing-usb-entries-in-windows-7/), where they inspect various registry entries and the logfile in: `...\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log` to get first connection date, but how to get last connection is more unclear. (Supposedly by comparing `\NTUSER\<username>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\MountPoints2` data, but I could not find it.)
4. Also the book "[Windows Registry Forensics: Advanced Digital Forensic Analysis of the Windows Registry](https://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=9780128033357)" also offers some additional hints to (3) from page 95 and on.

A potentially useful PS one-liner is:

```powershell
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational | where {$_.Id -eq "2003" -or $_.Id -eq "2102"} | Format-Table –Property TimeCreated, Id, Message -AutoSize -Wrap
```

This give the timestamps for the Events (2003, 2102) with the Message content, that could be further parsed.

```powershell
TimeCreated           Id Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-----------           -- -------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
2017-11-09 13:37:04 2102 Forwarded a finished Pnp or Power operation (27, 2) to the lower driver for device                                                                                                                                       
                         SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_G2&REV_PMAP#YYYYY&0#{XXXXX} with status 0x0.                                                            
2017-11-09 13:37:04 2102 Forwarded a finished Pnp or Power operation (27, 23) to the lower driver for device                                                                                                                                      
                         SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_G2&REV_PMAP#YYYYY&0#{XXXXX} with status 0x0.                                                            
2017-11-09 13:34:38 2003 The UMDF Host Process ({XXXXX}) has been asked to load drivers for device                                                                                                                 
                         SWD\WPDBUSENUM\_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_G2&REV_PMAP#YYYYY&0#{XXXXX}.                                                                            
2017-11-06 15:18:41 2102 Forwarded a finished Pnp or Power operation (27, 2) to the lower driver for device SWD\WPDBUSENUM\{XXXXX}#0000000000007E00 with status 0x0.                                               
2017-11-06 15:18:41 2102 Forwarded a finished Pnp or Power operation (27, 23) to the lower driver for device SWD\WPDBUSENUM\{XXXXX}#0000000000007E00 with status 0x0.                                              
2017-11-06 15:18:13 2003 The UMDF Host Process ({XXXXX}) has been asked to load drivers for device SWD\WPDBUSENUM\{XXXXX}#0000000000007E00.
```

Comment: Are you running this under the system account? Apparently, you need you need `nt authority\system` permissions to peek any deeper then: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\<drive>\Properties\`. Have you tried to pull your information with e.g. `RegEdit.exe`?

Comment: @iRon Funny, I am not able to access that, even though I am Admin.

Comment: Try [PSEXEC -i -s -d PowerShell.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008/) and then RegEdit or your script.

Comment: That doesn't work either as I get "The handle is invalid." error. Please, note that I'm already running all shells as `Administrator`, so what do you mean with "system account"?

Comment: See: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/10/22/getting-a-cmd-prompt-as-system-in-windows-vista-and-windows-server-2008/ to start a interactive prompt under the SYSTEM account. Basically the SYSTEM is account is use by the system itself. Note that a `Administrator` can't access everything intermediately that is handled by the system. And it will be even a bigger challenge if you want to do this remotely...

Comment: Using PowerShell command `Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_IT1165&Prod_USB_Flash_Disk&Rev_0.00\000000005BE51F59&0\' -Name *` revealed a lot of information. However, I do not see anything about timesamps for usage.

Comment: Following @iRon recommendation, I've managed to finally open Properties (psexec downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't complete but should get you started?

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

/// <summary>
/// Wraps a RegistryKey object and corresponding last write time.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// .NET doesn't expose the last write time for a registry key 
/// in the RegistryKey class, so P/Invoke is required.
/// </remarks>
public class RegistryKeyEx
{
    #region P/Invoke Declarations
    // This declaration is intended to be used for the last write time only. int is used
    // instead of more convenient types so that dummy values of 0 reduce verbosity.
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
    extern private static int RegQueryInfoKey(
        SafeRegistryHandle hkey,
        int lpClass,
        int lpcbClass,
        int lpReserved,
        int lpcSubKeys,
        int lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
        int lpcbMaxClassLen,
        int lpcValues,
        int lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
        int lpcbMaxValueLen,
        int lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
        IntPtr lpftLastWriteTime);
    #endregion
    #region Public Poperties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the registry key owned by the info object.
    /// </summary>
    public RegistryKey Key { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the last write time for the corresponding registry key.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime LastWriteTime { get; private set; }
    #endregion
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new RegistryKeyInfo object from the provided RegistryKey object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">RegistryKey component providing a handle to the key.</param>
    public RegistryKeyEx(RegistryKey key)
    {
        Key = key;
        SetLastWriteTime();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and initializes a new RegistryKeyInfo object from a registry key path string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parent">Parent key for the key being loaded.</param>
    /// <param name="keyName">Path to the registry key.</param>
    public RegistryKeyEx(RegistryKey parent, string keyName)
        : this(parent.OpenSubKey(keyName))
    { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Queries the currently set registry key through P/Invoke for the last write time.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetLastWriteTime()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Key != null, "RegistryKey component must be initialized");
        GCHandle pin = new GCHandle();
        long lastWriteTime = 0;
        try
        {
            pin = GCHandle.Alloc(lastWriteTime, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            if (RegQueryInfoKey(Key.Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, pin.AddrOfPinnedObject()) == 0)
            {
                LastWriteTime = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)pin.Target);
            }
            else
            {
                LastWriteTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pin.IsAllocated)
            {
                pin.Free();
            }
        }
    }
}
"@

$type = Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -Language CSharp

$devices = Get-Item HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR\*

$result = foreach($device in $devices) {
    Write-Verbose -Verbose "New device: $($device.PSPath)"

    Write-Verbose -Verbose "GetClass"
    foreach($classname in $device.GetSubKeyNames()) {
        $class = $device.OpenSubKey($class)

        if($class -eq $null) { 
            Write-Verbose -Verbose "Class is null" 
            continue
        }

        Write-Verbose -Verbose "GetInstance"
        foreach($instancename in $class.GetSubKeyNames()) {
            $instance = $class.OpenSubKey($instancename)

            if($instance -eq $null) {
                Write-Verbose -Verbose "Instance is null"
                continue
            }

            Write-Verbose -Verbose "RegistryKeyEx"
            $keyEx = New-Object RegistryKeyEx $instance

            [pscustomobject]@{
                FriendlyName = $keyEx.key.GetValue('FriendlyName')
                DevicePath = $device.PSPath
                LastWriteTime = $keyEx.LastWriteTime
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: (by not2qubit)

This script is in-line C# sharp. The current version give the following output:

```
VERBOSE: New device: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Kingston&Prod_DataTraveler_G2&Rev_PMAP
VERBOSE: GetClass
VERBOSE: GetInstance
VERBOSE: RegistryKeyEx
VERBOSE: New device: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_WD&Prod_My_Passport_0730&Rev_1015
VERBOSE: GetClass
VERBOSE: Class is null
VERBOSE: New device: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR\Other&Ven_WD&Prod_SES_Device&Rev_1015
VERBOSE: GetClass
VERBOSE: GetInstance
VERBOSE: RegistryKeyEx
```

Thus missing time stamps...

Edit:

Unless you look into the `$result` variable.

```
PS C:\> $result

FriendlyName                    DevicePath                                                                                                                           LastWriteTime      
------------                    ----------                                                                                                                           -------------      
Corsair Survivor 3.0 USB Device Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Corsair&Prod_Survivor_3.0&Rev_1.00 2017-11-05 21:08:25

PS C:\> get-date

November 11, 2017 17:02:09
```

This gives you what the guy has in your C# code example. Whether this information is accurate enough for your needs, I can't say.

Comment: I didn't down-vote your answer, but would still appreciate to know more about what you do different from what I already posted. Also look weird as you seem to be mixing PS with C#...

Comment: The script you provided doesn't give any time-stamps. I added the output to your answer. Please edit to show what you get, if incorrect.

Comment: Oh you seem to be missing the fact that I put everything into `$result`.

Comment: Ah, that is much better! But it seem to only get the first device instance (from what was found as I edited), the second is partially empty because of `Class is null` and the 3rd one is not shown at all.

Comment: Any idea why switching the order of: `DevicePath = ...` and `LastWriteTime = ...` gives very different results?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The order of columns in the console output changes, but that's the only difference I see?
I also included some `foreach()` loops to take into account devices with more than one instance and class, but I'm not familiar with how this registry information is constructed, so I can't really say what it means that a device has multiple instances or classes. Like I said in my post, all this is is a working implementation of the C# example you provided.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case it's only listing two devices whereas I have a lot of USB devices connected. For instance it doesn't show Lenovo Dock Gen 2 and also devices connected to USB sockets of this Dock like mouse, keyboard, etc.